# System.Security.SecurityException from SmtpClient.Send

Tags: .net, security

Security Exception
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

webconfig

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

code

```
SmtpClient sc_mail = new SmtpClient();
            sc_mail.Host = "***";
            sc_mail.Port = 25;
            sc_mail.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("***", "****");
            sc_mail.EnableSsl = true;
            sc_mail.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            MailMessage mesaj = new MailMessage();
            MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("***");
            mesaj.From = fromAddress;
            mesaj.To.Add("***");
            mesaj.Subject = "İletişim Formu";
            mesaj.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mesaj.Body = "Ad Soyad: " + name.Value + "<br />Yaşadığınız Şehir: " + city.Value + "<br />Telefon: " + phone.Value + "<br />E-Posta: " + email.Value + "<br />Notlar: " + comment.Value;
            sc_mail.Send(mesaj);
        }
        else
            buttonblue.Value = "Gizlilik Sözleşmesi!!!";
```

Comment: Your Web.config is missing the `<system.net><mailsettings>` configuration. The exception you see is from accessing the machine.config which is uses as a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the property "EnableSsl", it might work like that..